Connected GA4 property through Universal analytics after July 2024
I wasn't sure from the Email below sent by Google (Shortened a bit) if Universal tracking code in my website will continue to function and send data to GA4. Because I'm still using the old tags and not the new GA4 tags, but it works through the connected property.
Does anyone know if the code has to be updated, including all the event tracking and in Tag manager? Not using goals, conversions and advertiser type stuff anyway.
Does anyone share this situation?
The email:
Hello Google Analytics user,
On 1 July 2024, Google Analytics 4 properties will have fully replaced Universal Analytics properties, as previously announced. From that date, Google will begin turning off all Universal Analytics services and Universal Analytics APIs, which means Universal Analytics properties will be inaccessible through the Google Analytics front end and APIs. If you haven’t completely migrated to Google Analytics 4 properties, follow the migration guide to start making the switch today.
Product integrations
Universal Analytics data and settings accessed or used through advertiser, publisher or other product integrations will be unavailable when services have stopped. For example:
Universal Analytics goals and e-commerce transactions will stop measuring new conversions, including within linked advertising accounts. This may affect ad campaign performance if those conversions are used in combination with Smart Bidding.
Universal Analytics audience lists will be closed, which may affect ad campaign media activation and performance.
API requests related to Universal Analytics properties will fail, including requests for deletion of Universal Analytics data through the User Deletion API. This also means that tools relying on an API, such as Looker Studio, will not show any Universal Analytics data.
BigQuery export and backfill of historical data from Universal Analytics 360 properties can only be requested up to and including 30 June 2024. Already exported data remains available in BigQuery.
Attribution projects that were part of Attribution (beta) in Google Analytics will be deleted.
Sincerely,
The Google Analytics Team
Not got a bug yet but might turn into one if my GA stops working

Looks like Google finally got back...
tl;dr - Universal analytics will stop working even through GA4.
"On 1 July 2024, Google Analytics 4 properties will have fully replaced Universal Analytics properties, as previously announced. From that date, Google will begin turning off all Universal Analytics services and Universal Analytics APIs, which means Universal Analytics properties will be inaccessible through the Google Analytics front end and APIs. If you haven’t completely migrated to Google Analytics 4 properties, follow the migration guide to start making the switch today.
Exporting your data
To maintain access to data from your Universal Analytics property, you should download or export your data now. If this isn’t done through one of the methods provided in the Google Analytics Help Centre, your data will be permanently deleted by Google and won’t be recoverable. If you intend to use the BigQuery integration to export historical data from your Universal Analytics 360 property, we strongly recommend initiating this immediately.
Product integrations
Universal Analytics data and settings accessed or used through advertiser, publisher or other product integrations will be unavailable when services have stopped. For example:
Universal Analytics goals and e-commerce transactions will stop measuring new conversions, including within linked advertising accounts. This may affect ad campaign performance if those conversions are used in combination with Smart Bidding.
Universal Analytics audience lists will be closed, which may affect ad campaign media activation and performance.
API requests related to Universal Analytics properties will fail, including requests for deletion of Universal Analytics data through the User Deletion API. This also means that tools relying on an API, such as Looker Studio, will not show any Universal Analytics data.
BigQuery export and backfill of historical data from Universal Analytics 360 properties can only be requested up to and including 30 June 2024. Already exported data remains available in BigQuery.
Attribution projects that were part of Attribution (beta) in Google Analytics will be deleted."
Sincerely,
The Google Analytics Team

This is a letter for those who at one time configured GA4 through the settings manager in order to update universal analytics to GA4, i.e. for those who do not have a new G-*** type counter on the site, but UA-**** and exactly through it, the data enters GA4
Accordingly, if you want to receive events in the future, you need to update the Google Analytics tracking code.

Thanks, can you please expand on the basis of this as I need to be certain.
